# Writing functions and adding results to data frame

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I'm trying to create a function, that adds a score of the outcome to a data frame that I'm creating, but when I run the function, it converts the data frame to a value. My code looks as follows:

```
library(dplyr)

strenght <- 0
endurance <- 0
precision <- 0
technique <- 0
speed <- 0
playerScore <- data.frame(strenght, endurance, precision, technique, speed)

test1 <- function(test1time, test1goal) {
  if(test1time <= 1000) {
    speed <- speed + 3.5
  } else if(test1time >= 1001 & test1time <= 1350) {
    speed <- speed + ((350 - (test1time - 1000))/100)
  } else {
    speed <- speed + 0
  }

  if(test1goal == 1){
    precision <- precision + 0.5
  } else {
    precision <- precision + 0
  }
}

playerScore <- test1(1025, 1)
```

First I create a data frame filled with the value zero, because no tests have been run yet. Then I define the function for the first test. The test takes two arguments: Number of seconds the player took to finish the test (test1time) and number of goals scored (test1goal).

If a player gets the test done in less than ten seconds, he should be rewarded with 3.5 points to his speed score in the dataframe. Every 0.1 second above this should deduct 0.1 points from this score (and so on). Similarly the test should work so that if the player scores a goal, he should get 0.5 points to his precision score in the data frame.

However, I can't get the code to work - can anyone help me see where I went wrong with this?

EDIT: The wanted result should be:

```
> str(playerScore)
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ strenght : num 0
 $ endurance: num 0
 $ precision: num 0.5
 $ technique: num 0
 $ speed    : num 3.25
```

However when I run the script the result is that the data frame "playerScore" is converted to a value with the value 0.5

Comment: What do you think your function is returning? What exactly do you mean by "can't get the code to work"?

Comment: When I run everything, the result is that the data frame is converted to a value equal to 0.5, so I made an error somewhere, but I spend all day on it, and I can't get it to work. What is should return should be:
    > str(playerScore)
    'data.frame': 1 obs. of  5 variables:
     $ strenght : num 0
     $ endurance: num 0
     $ precision: num 0.5
     $ technique: num 0
     $ speed    : num 3.25
But it is simply converted to a value instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this, comments in the code explain changes from your original code.

```
library(dplyr)

test1 <- function(test1time, test1goal) {

  strenght <- 0
  endurance <- 0
  precision <- 0
  technique <- 0
  speed <- 0

  if(test1time <= 1000) {
    speed <- speed + 3.5
  } else if(test1time >= 1001 & test1time <= 1350) {
    speed <- speed + ((350 - (test1time - 1000))/100)
  } else {
    speed <- speed + 0
  }

  if(test1goal == 1){
    precision <- precision + 0.5
  } else {
    precision <- precision + 0
  }

  return(data.frame(strenght, endurance, precision, technique, speed))

  }
```

Your output:

```
test1(1025, 1)
  strenght endurance precision technique speed
1        0         0       0.5         0  3.25
```

Now you are able to add this information to your original dataframe `playerScore` every time you want, like this:

```
playerScore<-rbind(playerScore,test1(1025, 1))
playerScore<-rbind(playerScore,test1(1030, 8))
playerScore<-rbind(playerScore,test1(26, 1))
playerScore
  strenght endurance precision technique speed
1        0         0       0.0         0  0.00
2        0         0       0.5         0  3.25
3        0         0       0.0         0  3.20
4        0         0       0.5         0  3.50
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That returns the exact this I need it to. One quick thing: when I run playerScore <- test1(1025, 1) it converts the data frame from a df of 5 variables to a df of only the two variables ($speed and $precision) Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Yes, this is wrong.Code added according to this point in the answer

Comment: Thank you very much! I also tried just adding the other three variables to the return command (which works, since they doesn't contain anything), but this seems like a better solution :-)

Comment: Final question (sorry): I want to be able to create "test 2" and have the results accumulate. However when I try to add the score for test 2, it replaces the score. Any nifty solution for this?

Comment: Answer changed, now you are able to add additional rows to you original dataframe